# Execute or Print a C variable on bash without creating a file

Tags: c

So, I have this code below, the execsh is a small shell script, however I would need to run this shell script without creating the execsh file.
Would anyone have any idea? I would need to copy or print the content of array2 variable in someway where I could execute it in bash shell without having to add this content to a file.

Something like:

```
system("bash -c 'CONTENT OF ARRAY2');
```

Here is my code today:

```
FILE* g = fopen(".execsh", "w");
 if (g != NULL)
  {
       fprintf(g, "%s", array2);
            fclose(g);
                 g = NULL;
                  }
system("sh -x .execsh");
```

Comment: On a POSIX C implementation, this could be handled cleanly, if a bit verbosely, via `fork` / `execlp` / `wait`.  That would be of particular use for avoiding the quoting problems you are otherwise likely to have with embedding shell code in a shell command. And given that you're running shell code, it is reasonably likely that this would be a viable option for you.

Comment: Do you need to execute it with `bash` or `sh`? You have `bash -c` in the first `system()`, but `sh -x` in the second one.

Comment: In addition to other answers, you can `FILE *f = popen("/bin/bash", "w")`, then `fprintf(f, ...); pclose(f);`

Comment: Using `sh -s`, the shell reads the script from standard input.  That avoids creating a file.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to execute specifically with `bash`, but can use `sh` instead, just pass the string directly to `system()`.

```
system(array2);
```

This is equivalent to `sh -c "contents of array2 variable"`